# Changing a number within a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I randomly generate a matrix. Let's assume for simplicity that it is in the following form `np.shape(A) = (2,4)`:

```
import numpy as np
A:

matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
    [ 3,  4, 10,  8]])
```

Then, I estimate the following expression:

```
import numpy as np
K = 3
I = 4
C0 = np.sum(np.maximum(A[-1] - K, 0)) / I
```

The question is how do I input the following restriction: if any number of a column in the matrix `A` is less than or equal to (<=) K (3), then change the last number of that column to zero? So basically, my matrix should transform to this:

```
A:

matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
    [ 0,  0, 0,  8]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way.

```
A[-1][np.any(A <= 3, axis=0)] = 0

# matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
#         [0, 0, 0, 8]])

A[-1][np.any((A > 2) & (A <= 3), axis=0)] = 0

# matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
#         [0, 4, 0, 8]])
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped! just one clarifying question, how do i impose the restriction between two values? A[-1][np.any(2<A <= 3, axis=0)] = 0 did not work for me

Comment: thank you! Sorry for disturbing you again... One clarification, how do I modify the code I want to change the last entry of a column based on the difference between the last entry and 5, I tried this a[-1][np.any(a <= 3, axis=0)] = np.maximum(a[-1], 5)   but it a[-1][np.any(a <= 3, axis=0)] = np.maximum(a[-1], 5)